# How to connect cli-app with IOTA Javascript Library

Tags: iri-node, wallet, iri-legacy-api, cli-wallet, iota-cli

I installed [IOTA CLI Wallet](https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app) and executing 'iota-cli' works after iri is executed. I get NodeInfo command run on iota-cli from my terminal also. So I guess a stand alone IOTA wallet core is now installed on my server.

But I needed to interact with IOTA node via browser. For that i installed [IOTA Javascript Library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) in public html of my server. 
The library also seems to be installed.

- I have left Neighbors field empty in iri.ini file. Is that okay?
- The API documentation seems very easy also. But i don't know where to put api calls specified in documentation.
- Should I write a html file in public root including iota.js in script src and also include the api calls below that in another script tag. I tried this method and got error below in console

> lineNumber: 3745
>   message: "Invalid Response: "

- I have done so much of searching. I found nothing that fits me. That may be because of wrong keywords. Please suggest a complete beginners guide apart from official API documentation. I understand that but don't know where to call those scripts as mentioned above.
- I am a total newbie to this cryptocurrency stuff. **Please help.** and if you find this question unsuitable please suggest another forum to ask. And please comment below on improving this question before you downvote

**UPDATE**:
How to specify neighbors in iri.ini file. An example with random ip and port no would be really helpful.

Comment: did you figure out this? I am looking for something similar